# How to get the children values dynamically using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <row>
      <first-name>John</first-name>
      <last-name>Miller</last-name>
      <address>Birmingham</address>
   </row>
   <row>
      <first-name>Rose</first-name>
      <last-name>Miller</last-name>
      <address>New York</address>
   </row>
</root>
```

I want to modify the xml using XSLT in such a way that my output is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <row>
      <Name>John-Miller</Name>
      <address>Birmingham</address>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Name>Rose-Miller</Name>
      <address>New York</address>
   </row>
</root>
```

To summarize, I want to concatenate the `<first-name>` and `<last-name>` to generate a new node called `<Name>` and keep the `<address>` tag as it is(same thing should happen in each `<row>`).

I am trying with the following XSLT, but not getting the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="row">
      <row>
         <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(//first-name,'-',//last-name)" />
         </Name>
      </row>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run the above XSLT against my input xml, I am only getting the `<first-name>` and `<last-name>` values of only first row. 
Could you please provide the solution?

Comment: In your expected output why in the second row element contains john-miller..shouldn't it be Rose-Miller??

Comment: @Saurav  I am sorry..Typo error...You are correct..Updated the question now..Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a relative path meaning you need to replace `<xsl:value-of select="concat(//first-name,'-',//last-name)" />` with `<xsl:value-of select="concat(first-name,'-',last-name)" />`. And you need to make sure to copy the address as well:

```
   <xsl:template match="row">
      <row>
         <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(first-name,'-',last-name)" />
         </Name>
         <xsl:copy-of select="address"/>
      </row>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's perfect...+1 for quick solution. :)